# How do you make buttons re sizable at run time?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, resize

I want to make it so that my buttons change size based on the text inside them. Kind of like a Label with it's height and width set to "Auto", but I would like to start with a pre-determined dimension.

Is there a way to place a button, size it, and allow for re-sizing based on run-time text changes? If so, how do I do this?

I've looked at this example:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/188c196e-90d8-4584-bc62-38d7e008cf5c/how-do-i-resize-button-text-upon-button-resize

It has to do with inserting a textblock on top of the button, but when the text adjusts sometimes the new text becomes too small because the text does not wrap for some reason...

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking abt re-sizing the actual `Button` control when it's `Content` which could be text changes or are you talking abt changing font-size and sorts of the text in a button to fit the `Button` like the link you've posted? Also in WPF `Button`'s are always re-sizable unless you've limited their re-sizing capability by specifying hard-coded dimensions. Am just confused what it is you're trying to achieve. Normally you do not set any dimensions on WPF control's and let the layout control's manage that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the **MinWidth** and **MinHeight** properties so that you start with a predetermined size and the button will be able to grow with text.

Unfortunately this would not allow the button to get smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to size it based on its content, then. That is, have no XAML defined size.

Elements on the page normally size themselves to their children.

Comment: How is that different than using Auto for height and width?

-Basically just get rid of any XAML sizing?

Comment: [Auto is the default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773541/wpf-control-default-size).